# MS MVC form AJAXifying techniques

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms

I'm looking for **most elegant** way to ajaxify my forms (with jQuery).
How do you do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a poll.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my solution (I think it is a [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) solution), using only jQuery without any plugins:

```
var form = $('form#YourFormId');
$(':submit', form).click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(),
        function(data, status) {
            if(status == 'success') {
                // your code here
            }
        }
    );
});
```

**UPDATED:**

If your POST response is "HTML with form" then try this:

```
function ajaxifyForm(form) {
    $(':submit', form).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(),
            function(data, status) {
                if(status == 'success') {
                    var newForm = $(data);
                    ajaxifyForm(newForm);
                    form.after(newForm).remove();
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: This looks like what i`m looking for. Got to try...

Comment: In "your code here" part i wrote $("form#YourFormId).html(data);. After first hit everything goes smoothly. But, on 2nd hit it posts fields unchanged, binds my formModel wrong and gets wrong response. :/

Comment: I've updated my answer but it is not tested

Comment: On 2nd hit it calls my "home/index" and renders whole page inside previous one. I`m trying to 'ajaxify' login widget only. Tried "if(status=='success'){form.html(data);ajaxifyForm(form);}", but then there's that strange behaviour again i mentioned already.

Comment: The problem is in form.html(data) function. You insert your response in your existing. Your should remove old form and then add new form just after that (form.after(newForm).remove();)

Comment: Replace form.html(data); with form.after(newForm).remove();

Comment: @eu-ge-ne this method would be even better, if it could accept form which is needed to be serialized, target html element which is needed to be updated and parameters list with additional parameters for posting to serverside (i.e.: 'form.serialize()+"&pageIndex=5"').

Answer (score 6):

Ajaxify your forms... that is pretty vague.

If you want to submit a form asynchronously, you could use $.post() to post to a separate controller action.

Example:

In the view:

```
$.post('<%= Url.Action("DoAjaxCall") %>', $('form').serialize(), 
function (data) {
    alert(data.Message);
}
, "json");
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult DoAjaxCall(YourModel model)
{
    return Json(new { Message = "Your ajax call is working!" });
}
```

That is what I'm using in some of my forms at least.

P.S.: I wrote this in the stackoverflow text editor so it's not really tested. But as an outline, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [JQuery plugins storage](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/47) I'm sure there you will find that you need

Comment: I found jQuery Form plugin. It looks nice, but i`m not sure how to use it properly.

Comment: ok all you need is to include founded plugin to your site.master and create function on dom ready that will do your logic on form submit.
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/form here comes good sample and here, how to be within http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: I want to simplify that. Perfect solution would be something like adding 1 short JS function call in form onload. You know - in more compact and declarative way. I don't want all my views messed up with <script (..)>$(document).ready(function() {var options = {target: "#myForm" }; $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); });</script>

Comment: I meant that you need to add one short row like this $(':submit', form) in site.master in this case all your submits will go via ajax.
Another solution is to create your own Template for Edit, Create View
and add additional script to this template. In this case when you will create new views all you need is to decide will current view submit via Ajax or not.