# MVC3 partial view postback not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have LogOn partial view in the AccountController :

```
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOn

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.Account.Account.LoginFailureText);
                }
            }
        }

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

, I render this partial in my _Layout.cshtml with:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");}
```

and the LogOn.cshtml view is :

```
@model Kalimat.Web.Models.LogOnModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="leftbanner login">
    <div class="bookicon">
        <img src="@Url.Content(@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Common.bookiconImgSrc)" alt="@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Common.bookiconImgAlt" />
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
        @MvcHtmlString.Create(Kalimat.Web.Resources.Account.Account.LoginTitle)
    </div>
    <div class="shade_2">
        <img src="@Url.Content(@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Common.shade_2ImgSrc)" alt="@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Common.shade_2ImgAlt" />
    </div>
    <div class="insidetext">
        @{
            //Logined user view
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <div id="LoginView1">
                    @{<text>@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Account.Account.WelcomeText <strong>@Model.UserName</strong>!</text>}
                    <br />
                    <a id="LoginStatus1" href="">@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Account.Account.LoginStatusText</a>
                    <a id="ChangePassLinkButton" href="">@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Account.Account.ChangePswText</a>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "inputfield" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "*")
                <br />
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "inputfield" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "*")
                <br />
                <span class="remove_shop">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                </span>
                <p>
                    ***<input type="submit" class="submit_Cart" value="@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Account.Account.LoginButtonText" />***
                </p>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(false, Kalimat.Web.Resources.Account.Account.LoginFailureText)
                <a class="submit_Cart" href="">@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Account.Account.NewAccountText</a>
                <br />
                <a class="submit_Cart" href="">@Kalimat.Web.Resources.Account.Account.RecoverPswText</a>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

when I run the application the LogOn view render correct but when clicking on the submit button nothing happens. why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first stop duplicating this line

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {}
```

doesn't make sense ...

as by looking to your code, you have submit button and everything but i think you missing

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm())
{
     //put all your html element in this
     // and also put submit button in it ...
}
```

here is the parameters for Ajax.BeginForm():

```
Ajax.BeginForm(
    string "ActionName",
    string "ControllerName",
    new routevalues {id="IDValue",message="MyMessage"},
    new AjaxOptions {OnBegin=[someFunction], OnFailure=[failureFunction] },
    new { id = "FormName" }
)
```

this is because you using ajax to post your action ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when using this solution the view first time displayed with the validation errors and when submit the view it not rendered to reflect that the user is logged until refreshing the page

Comment: are you using 

Html.EnableClientValidation();

before ajax.beginform()? and in your action when you fulfilling all your checks like user is validated then you don't have to render the same html ... as you already used the form so create another div on the control that use same model but says user logged in or something and in this add UpdateTargetId attr:

new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = [divid], OnBegin=[someFunction], OnFailure=[failureFunction] }

so when action is successfull it'll show this div instead of that ... but it's totally upto you how you manage ur rendered html ...

Comment: chk this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733541/rendering-view-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks, the validation is always displayed because I forget to add the style sheet

Comment: Now I have another problem when main view perform HttpPost the application validate this partial view, how can I stop this behavior????

Comment: can you put some code, so I can see what's happening ... and are you validating the partial view before it is render?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see if you have your submit in a form?

you should be adding:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account"))
{
    // Submit form bits here
}
```

around your login bits to submit the information?

Comment: Luke, First thanks for your answer ,second it works but I have new problems (1)The LogOn view displayed with the validation errors seconed when I press the submit the view not changed to reflect that the user is logged until refresh the page!!??

Comment: Have you tried dvlpr's suggestion? my fault for not noticing you were running a partial. It might be more suitable for your use? as for the `Request.IsAuthenticated` think about it... you have submitted back to the page and the status would be false, just because you are calling the `FormService` halfway the process does not make the Request.IsAuthenticated change to true. I would set something in the `Model` or a `ViewBag` property to say that you are logged in.

Comment: thanks Luke, i use the ViewBag and now the application running

Answer (score -1):

Please, check if you have added any hidden field in the form that is going null. In simple words, there should be nothing that not required to null and posting as null.

For example, I was posting form (For create) with hidden field of ID (Primary), so Id will be null in the create instance so model is in valid and its looking like any thing not posting.

Comment: Would you mind to rephrase your sentences? It's somehow hard to get the idea you're trying to pass.