# PartialView form validation then calling a controller method in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, validation

I am very new to MVC3 and having problems wrapping my head around things. Right now I have a partial view which I have simplified below:

```
@model blah.blah.blah.blah.ForumPost

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<fieldset>
    <legend>ForumPost</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ForumID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ForumID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ForumID)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    </p>
</fieldset>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
}
```

I am not what to do for form validation. I have been trying to using jquery validation but I cant seem to find a good example that fits what I am doing and just get lost. I was basing it off this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940910/mvc3-partial-view-postback-not-work) but it isn't enough.

After I am done I want to call a method in some code and I am  not really sure of a clean way to do this. The way I have it currently working is using an ajax call and it's really ugly. Also a colleague suggested I pass the method an actual forum post but I don't know how. The code for the method I want to call is below:

```
public void PostToForum(ForumPost post)
{
    UserService cu = new UserService();
    int PostUserID = cu.GetUserIDByUsername(base.User.Identity.Name);

    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ForumPost nfp = service.CreateForumPost(post);
    }
}
```

Anyone have some tips? Thanks.

I can provide more code if it's necessary.

Comment: There is no 'code behind' in MVC3

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni sorry, like I said I am very new to MVC3 and I wasn't sure what to call it.

Comment: No problem, no need to apologize. It's a very different approach to controls-on-pages-with-weird-things-called-lifecycle.

Comment: Off-Topic: @yagerbomb you should consider writing more readable code. Your variable naming is very cryptic and hard to understand for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html forms are usually submitted to controller actions:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ForumPost model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // validation failed => redisplay the view so that the user can fix the errors
        return View(model);
    }

    // at this stage the model is valid => process it:
    service.CreateForumPost(model);

    return ...
}
```

Now since this is a partial view you must be careful with the view you are returning from this controller action as well as the model. If you don't use AJAX you should return the entire parent view and the parent view model. If you use an AjaxForm then you could only work with the partial model and view. Also in this case in the event of success you could return a Json result to the view to indicate this success so that the javascript handler that will be executed could take the respective actions.

Comment: how does the html form know to call this method?

Comment: It's up to you to indicate this when generating the form: `@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))`. If you don't do so (as in your code `@using (Html.BeginForm())`), the controller action that will be invoked must have the same name as the controller action that was used to render this form except that it must be decorated with the HttpPost attribute. So for example if your view was rendered with a Create controller action (`/somecontroller/create`) then if you don't specify an action when generating the form the Create POST controller action will be invoked when you submit.

Comment: Ah okay. I understand. Apparently in this project nothing with validation has been started yet which is why I have been completely lost. To many things are disorganized and such. This made a lot more since now as I see what exactly is being passed and such. Thanks!