# self ajax partial view in MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view inside a div with id 'rating'. So I have a ajax link inside the same partial view. So when I click on the link its updating one time and if i click the link second time, its loading the div two times and clicking three times load multiple times.

Anybody have the same issue?

```
<div class="rating"> 
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Flag this review as inappropriate", "CourseRatingFlag", "Content", new { cID = Model.courseRatings[index].crid}, new AjaxOptions() {  HttpMethod = "POST",TargetId="rating" })
some content...
  </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-AJAX-updating partial-view/controller in ASP.Net MVC and the duplicating div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931001/self-ajax-updating-partial-view-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-and-the-duplicating-di)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931001/self-ajax-updating-partial-view-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-and-the-duplicating-di).

In my case, I resolved it locating the target div out of the partial view.