# ASP.Net MVC, Submit a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a form on one of my ASP.Net MVC views that I created using the following code

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
```

Using this code I have no control as far as I am aware of setting the name of the form. I'm now trying to write a javascript function to submit the form, is this possible without knowing the forms name?

Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use jquery to submit the form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm"})) { %>
```

(the last part is for htmlAttributes parameter)

just do this:

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

and do not forget to include jquery-1.2.6.js that comes with mvc (or use a higher version).

Comment: I love how easy MVC makes things like this.

Comment: Either you have a bracket out of place or things have changed a bit since 2009! This is what worked for me using the Razor syntax: **@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form"}))** [Edit: Just noticed ajbeaven pointed this out in another answer]

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use jQuery without naming the form, and you will only have one form on the page, you can just add a link like this to your page:

```
<a href="#" class="submitForm">Submit</a>
```

And then add this jQuery which will wire up the link to submit **every** form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.submitForm").click(function () {
        $("form").submit();
    });
});
```

So this is a way of doing it (the way I just did it on my site) that doesn't require you to name the form - provided you only have one. Saying that, you may want to submit multiple forms ..

Comment: Slick solution. loved this answer. +1

Comment: `.submit()` causes redirect to the view returned by `POST` controller method. Is it possible to submit without redirect?

Comment: You could get the controller to return the same view with different data, and then show the user some kind of response. If you don't want the page to reload at all, you can ditch the form altogether and bind a Knockout view model to the page instead, and then post the data to the controller using a jQuery ajax call - that would allow you to post to the controller without posting a form in the classic sense.

Answer (score 4):

If you have only one form on that page, you can access the form by using:

```
document.forms[0].
```

So you could add a link:

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">submit form</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set name of the form, use object htmlAttributes parameter of BeginForm method.

```
<% using 
  (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post,
     new {name="MySuperForm"})) %>
```

For submitting forms through javascript, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930074/ms-mvc-form-ajaxifying-techniques). Might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution submit the Ajax form without post-back

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#sbmt').trigger('click'); return false">Generate</a>
<input id="sbmt" type="submit" style="visibility: hidden" />
```

Works in IE and Firefox.