# How to submit a form inside Razor view by Java Script function WITHOUT redirection?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

To submit form below I have to click `<input type="submit" value="Save" />` which is at the bottom of form pasted below:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 200px; font-weight: bold;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This causes invoking `POST Edit` method in `PersonController`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName")] Person person) {     
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(person);
}
```

I also would like to have a JavaScript function which does the same( when I invoke this function) but does not redirects me to any view. Just invokes `POST Edit` and passes contents of the form above.

**Question:** How to write JavaScript function which submits the form above without redirecting me anywhere?

```
 function SubmitForm() {}
```

---

### EDIT

I tried this.

The JavaScript method is invoked when I click `@Html.ActionLink("Add a Report", "Create", "Reports", new { personId = Model.Id }, new { onclick = "SubmitForm()" })` (alert is displayed) but form is not submited(standard submit button works, so it is JavaScript function fault).

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name="myForm", id = "myForm" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <p> @Html.ActionLink("Add a Report", "Create", "Reports", new { personId = Model.Id }, new { onclick = "SubmitForm()" })</p>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 200px; font-weight: bold;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and the function:

```
 function SubmitForm() {
            alert("IS INVOKED");
            $("#myForm").submit();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way I have found. :

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

Possible duplicate of. :

[ASP.Net MVC, Submit a form using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962229/asp-net-mvc-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

You also need to name your form.  In this instance myFrom is the id of your form.  Something like. :

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "myForm", id = "myForm" })
```

Comment: So:  `function SubmitForm() {$("#myForm").submit();}`? What is `#myForm`? Is it an `id` or `name` ?

Comment: added above in some logic above, might be different as you are probably doing a post....so you would change FormMethod.Post

Comment: Thanks I try it right now I tried without a name it didn't work.I'll try with a name and post comment if it not goint to work.

Comment: Ok, it didn't worked. I added edit to the original post. Could you have a look at it, please?

Comment: Do you have jquery included in your page.....that is the first question.  Second question after button is clicked do you make it to your controller for page?  Also, do you have a annotation above your controller?  Only allowing gets or posts?

Comment: Above I meant to say annotation above your action within your controller

Comment: Controller is in original post just before EDIT, there is annotation for POST. The submit button works(the standard one which submits form and redirects). 
Yes I have all jquery and similar included.

Comment: In debug mode with breakpoint on your action do you hit your breakpoint on submit?  If not you should run fiddler to see if a post is occurring upon button click and see what url is being posted.  Or if javascript error is occurring etc.

Comment: Unfortunately `submit()` will cause redirect. I tried this `<a href="#" class="submitForm">Submit</a>`

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.submitForm").click(function () {
        $("form").submit();
    });
});` Clicking the link caused redirection.

Comment: Have you tried a button input?  Just to rule out link clicking oddities?

Comment: What do you mean by trying button input? If you are asking is button input submits the form correctly, it does, but I need submitting a form without redirection anywhere.

Comment: Submitting the form to your controller is going to cause some sort of redirection per se in the sense that once it hits your controller it will provide your view back to your page.  If you just want to post the data to an action without the page changing, I would suggest performing an ajax post to an action other than the one responsible for your page being rendered.  Although personally I like submitting a form, but you have to deal with returning a view back from your action when you do so.

Comment: Did it: `function SubForm (){
            $.ajax({
                url:'/Person/Edit/@Model.Id/',
                type:'post',
                data:$('#myForm').serialize(),
                success:function(){
                    //alert("fasf");
                }
            });
        }`