# Why is my postback not working on Html.Actionlink or even button JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, postback

Here is my cshtml code and my jquery, I have tried this two different ways. When I click on my button approve, I expect it to go to the Action ApprovePoints with the parameters, but nothing happens

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ApprovePoints()
    {
        // Build out the Screen to Approve Points
        var model = new AdminPointsViewModel();
        var ptsToApprove = from x in db.CommunityPts
                           join y in db.CertPointTypes on x.TypeId equals y.TypeId
                           where x.Pending == true
                           select new AdminPoints
                           {
                               communityId = x.Community.CommunityId,
                               communityName = x.Community.ComunityName,
                               pointId = x.CertPoint.PointId,
                               pointDesc = x.CertPoint.PointDescription,
                               typeId = x.CertPoint.TypeId,
                               typeDesc = y.TypeName,
                               pointsExpected = x.CertPoint.Points,
                               pointsEarned = (int) x.PointsEarned,
                               dateApplied = (DateTime) x.DateApplied,


                           };
        model.adminPoints = ptsToApprove;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ApprovePoints(int cid, int pid)
    {
        var approvePts = db.CommunityPts.Where(x => x.CommunityId == cid && x.PointId == pid).SingleOrDefault();

        return View();

    }
}
```

Here is the markup and the jquery:

```
<form method="post">
<table border="1" style="border-color:white; border-width:thick;">
    <thead style="font-weight:bold">
        <tr>
            <th>Community</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Category Code</th>
            <th>Points Expected</th>
            <th>Points Earned</th>
            <th>Date Applied</th>
            <th>Approve</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @if (Model.adminPoints != null)
    {
        foreach (var pts in @Model.adminPoints)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@pts.communityName</td>
                <td>@pts.pointDesc</td>
                <td>@pts.typeDesc</td>
                <td>@pts.pointsExpected</td>
                <td>@pts.pointsEarned</td>
                <td>@Convert.ToDateTime(@pts.dateApplied).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Approve Points", "ApprovePoints", "Admin", new {cid= @pts.communityId, pid = @pts.pointId}, new {@class = "btn btn-default"})</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ApprovePoints(@pts.communityId, @pts.pointId);">Approve Points</a></td>
            </tr>
        }

    }
    else
    {
    <tr>
        <td>There are no points to approve at this time.</td>
    </tr>
    }

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
    </form>
<script>
    var ApprovePoints = (function (CommunityId, PointId) {


        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("id", CommunityId);
        data.append("pid", PointId);

        alert(data.get("id"));
        alert(data.get("pid"));

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Admin/ApprovePoints/",  
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            success: function () {

                window.location.href = "/Admin/ApprovePoints/" 
            },
            error: function (errorData) { alert(errorData); }


        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the point of passing the parameters to your post action if you are doing nothing with it? You do a query to the db but then you do not use the result from the query and return the same view all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might be missing some understanding of the technologies at work here. I believe your primary misconception is that you can call a C# function from JavaScript which you can not. Remember that at the time of rendering the cshtml view all of the c# is rendered to HTML via the Razor engine. What you're seeing in the browser is strictly HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You need to call to the MVC route to invoke the server-side function.

Open the browser console. Are you seeing the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ApprovePoints is not defined` when you click the link? That's because onclick is a javascript event handler and ApprovePoints is not a defined function.

You need to cause the form element to submit (by default form action will POST to the current route). You could cause the submit a # of ways. For example with elements:

```
<form>
   <input type="submit" value="Click to submit form"/>
   -- or --
   <button>Click to submit form</button>
</form>
```

Or with javscript

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
   document.getElementById('formid').submit()
}
</script>
```

See the documentation for form [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

You may gain some insight from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962229/asp-net-mvc-submit-a-form-using-javascript#962239) as well

Comment: Well, I am new to working with MVC, but I did use Ajax on HttpPost before so. none-the-less, I renamed the post action and removed the HttpPost on my action, and the action like worked. thanks for you help

Comment: Excellent. If my post helped answer your question don't forget to mark it as the answer for future people. Best of luck